# Gsap vertical or horizontal screen is not working Properly

Tags: javascript, gsap

I'm having an issue in gsap vertical and horizontal screen, it not stop on full page when i scroll

```js
let sections = gsap.utils.toArray(".section")

sections.forEach((section, i) => {
  if ( section.classList.contains('horizontal') ) {
          
      const cardsWrap = section.querySelector('.section__cards') 
      const oneCard = section.querySelector('.section__card') 
      
    
      gsap.to(cardsWrap, {
        x: () => { return -( (cardsWrap.scrollWidth - window.innerWidth + window.innerWidth*0.01) + (window.innerWidth/1 - oneCard.offsetWidth/1) ) },
        ease: "none",
        scrollTrigger: {
          trigger: section,
          start:() => "center center",
          end: () => "+=" + cardsWrap.scrollWidth,
          scrub: 1,
          pin:true,
          snap: 1 / (sections.length - 1),
          pin: i === sections.length -1 ? false : true,
          invalidateOnRefresh: true,
          anticipatePin: 1,
        },        
      });
        
  } else {
    
    ScrollTrigger.create({
      markers: false,
      trigger: section,
      start: () => "top top",
      pin:true,
      pin: i === sections.length -1 ? false : true,
      anticipatePin: 1,
    });
  } 
  
});
```